# How to use document viewer for many2many_binary widget in odoo

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, odoo-12

I would like to add a preview option for my attachments in the form view. I have a field in many2many_binary. and I have inherited the widget to add a custom icon. Now I click that icon it should show the preview of the document.
this is my sample code. To call my document viewer.

```
ev.stopPropagation();
ev.preventDefault();
var attachments = [{
            "filename": self.recordData.display_name ,
            "id": source_id,
            "is_main": true,
            "mimetype": "image/png",
            "name": self.recordData.display_name + " " + self.value
            "type": "image",
        }]
var attachmentViewer = new DocumentViewer(this,attachments,activeID);    
attachmentViewer.appendTo($('body'));
```

But it's showing you should provide a string or binary not an object like this.please help me.